# React - using forwardRef in component, typescript error - Property 'current' is missing

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-ref, react-forwardref

I'm struggling to understand why the typescript compiler is unhappy with the forwardRef I'm using in a component.

I've pared my code right down to the bare essentials for the example below, ensuring this typescript error is the only one that manifests in the code, as per the issue in my actual code:

```
import { createRef, forwardRef, RefObject } from 'react';

const MyComponent = () => {
    const selectCountryRef = createRef<HTMLSelectElement>();

    return (
        <div>
            <SelectCountry ref={selectCountryRef} />
        </div>
    );
};

const SelectCountry = forwardRef((ref?: RefObject<HTMLSelectElement>) => {
    return (
        <FormFieldSelect ref={ref} />
    );
});

const FormFieldSelect = ({ ref }) => {
    return (
        <div>
            <select ref={ref}>
            </select>
        </div>
    );
};
```

When trying to compile this, I get the error:

`Property 'current' is missing in type '{ ref: RefObject<HTMLSelectElement>; }' but required in type 'RefObject<HTMLSelectElement>'.`

In VSCode, `<SelectCountry ...` is where the IDE is having a whinge, the exact message is:

`const SelectCountry: ForwardRefExoticComponent<RefObject<HTMLSelectElement> & RefAttributes<unknown>> Property 'current' is missing in type '{ ref: RefObject<HTMLSelectElement>; }' but required in type 'RefObject<HTMLSelectElement>'.ts(2741) index.d.ts(85, 18): 'current' is declared here.`

I'm just failing to understand why I'm getting this error.

Currently using React 17.0.2

Answer (score 3):

`forwardRef` gets called with the `props` argument first and the `ref` argument second.

Your `ForwardRefRenderFunction` is using `ref?: RefObject<HTMLSelectElement>` as the **first** argument which is the props.  As far as TypeScript is concerned, the type of the props for `SelectCountry` is a `RefObject<HTMLSelectElement>`.  That's why you get the error:

> Property 'current' is missing in type `{ ref: RefObject<HTMLSelectElement>; }` but required in type `RefObject<HTMLSelectElement>`.

---

@jeffreyquan's answer shows you a properly-typed solution so I won't reiterate everything that they wrote.  You can assign types to the `props` and `ref` by setting the generic type parameters on the `forwardRef` function like they showed you.

You can also assign the types by annotating the `props` and `ref` arguments of the inner function like you were trying to do, but you need to make sure that it's done correctly.  If you don't assign any type to `props` then it gets inferred as `PropsWithChildren<{}>` which is actually fine here.  So this works:

```
const SelectCountry = forwardRef((props, ref: ForwardedRef<HTMLSelectElement>) => {
    return (
        <FormFieldSelect ref={ref} />
    );
});
```

In order to pass typechecking in strict mode you need to change `RefObject` to `ForwardedRef`.  This allows for callback refs and `null`.

Answer (score 2):

Try the following. I've added a `useEffect` and a `console.log` in `MyComponent` to show that it's working. I was confused with how you assigned `ref?: RefObject<HTMLSelectElement>` in `SelectCountry` and believe this was causing the error. I've shown how to assign types to `forwardRef` in the code snippet i.e. `forwardRef<RefElementType,ComponentPropsType>`. The `FormFieldSelect` also must be a `forwardRef` component.

```
import React, { useEffect, createRef, forwardRef } from 'react'

export const MyComponent = () => {
  const selectCountryRef = createRef<HTMLSelectElement>()

  useEffect(() => {
    console.log(selectCountryRef.current)
  }, [selectCountryRef])

  return (
    <div>
      <SelectCountry ref={selectCountryRef} />
    </div>
  )
}

interface SelectCountryProps {}

const SelectCountry = forwardRef<HTMLSelectElement, SelectCountryProps>(
  (props, ref) => {
    return <FormFieldSelect ref={ref} />
  },
)

interface FormFieldSelectProps {}

const FormFieldSelect = forwardRef<HTMLSelectElement, FormFieldSelectProps>(
  (props, ref) => {
    return (
      <div>
        <select ref={ref}></select>
      </div>
    )
  },
)
```

Comment: Oh, interesting! - that's given me food for thought, thanks!

My 'real world' example is a whole lot more complicated, obviously, but this adjustment of my basic code I posted, should give me the inspiration I need to solve the issue - looks like I need some refactoring.

The mention of the FormFieldSelect needing to be a forwardRef looks like the solution, once I can figure it out.

Comment: You're welcome @MatthewTrow :) Glad I could help. Could you please upvote my answer if you found it useful? And if it my answer helped resolve the original question, could you please accept it the answer? Any of this would really help me. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

I realize this is an older question, but I ran into this recently and this is what worked for me. Note that, per [React's documentation](https://beta.reactjs.org/reference/react/createRef), `createRef` is meant to be used with class components. Instead you should use the hook [`useRef`](https://beta.reactjs.org/reference/react/useRef). Also refer to [`forwardRef`](https://beta.reactjs.org/reference/react/forwardRef) for further helpful tips.

```
import { ChangeEventHandler, forwardRef, useRef, useState } from "react";

// This can be any type, but be sure to omit the `ref` prop if extending
// another interface/type
interface InputProps {
  value: string;
  onChange: (value: string) => void;
}

// Specify types on forwardRef instead of in the function
const Input = forwardRef<HTMLInputElement, InputProps>((props, ref) => {
  const handleChange: ChangeEventHandler<HTMLInputElement> = (event) => {
    props.onChange(event.target.value);
  };

  return (
    <input ref={ref} onChange={handleChange} value={props.value} type="text" />
  );
});

function App() {
  // 1. Use the hook `useRef`, not the function `createRef`
  // 2. Must match the first type passed to forwardRef
  // 3. Must have initial value set to `null`
  const inputRef = useRef<HTMLInputElement>(null);

  const [value, setValue] = useState("");

  return <Input ref={inputRef} value={value} onChange={setValue} />;
}
```